# I want that it should stop when the user entered 3 times wrong ID and Password (ID and PW are correct ones)

Tags: java, do-while

In my program it is ending when the user entered 3 times wrong ID and Password (ID and PW are correct ones)-there is no problem with ending-In the same time it says "welcome..." after saying "Your account has been blocked".

```
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);

    String ID2, PW2, PW = "qwerty123", ID = "theman" ; 
    int entry=0;
    do {entry++;
    System.out.println("Please enter you ID.");
        ID2 = enter.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter your password.");  
        PW2 = enter.nextLine();

    if(!(ID.equals(ID2)) && ((PW.equals(PW2)))) {
        System.out.println("Try again!");
    }
    else if((ID.equals(ID2)) && (!(PW.equals(PW2)))) {
        System.out.println("Try again!");
    }
    else if(!(ID.equals(ID2)) && !((PW.equals(PW2)))) {
        System.out.println("Try again!");
    }   
    if(entry==3) {
        System.out.println("**Your account has been blocked**");
        break;
    }                       
    }while(!(ID.equals(ID2)) && !((PW.equals(PW2))));
    System.out.println("Welcome...");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrongly", be specific!

Comment: Of course it says "welcome". The last line of the program is a println which tells the program to say "welcome". What else would you expect it to do!?

Comment: Just delete the last println()

Comment: If you run the program you are going to see that if the user enters wrong ıd or password program prints "try again" until user enters true Id and Password. Then it says "welcome" and it stops.So If I delete the last println() program won't have any meaning.

Comment: The `break` does not stop the program, it just terminates the enclosing while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);

    String ID2, PW2, PW = "qwerty123", ID = "theman";
    int entry = 0;
    do {
        entry++;
        System.out.println("Please enter you ID.");
        ID2 = enter.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter your password.");
        PW2 = enter.nextLine();

        if (ID.equals(ID2) && (PW.equals(PW2))) {
            System.out.println("Welcome...");
        } else if (!(ID.equals(ID2)) && ((PW.equals(PW2)))) {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
        } else if ((ID.equals(ID2)) && (!(PW.equals(PW2)))) {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
        } else if (!(ID.equals(ID2)) && !((PW.equals(PW2)))) {
            System.out.println("Try again!");
        }
        if (entry == 3) {
            System.out.println("**Your account has been blocked**");
            break;
        }
    } while (!(ID.equals(ID2)) && !((PW.equals(PW2))));

}
```